# Optimizing querying 78,000,000 row table (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, mysql-workbench

I have a table called tags_table with an id column of type `INT(11)` and a tag column of type `VARCHAR(200)`.

There are ~3,000,000 unique ids, and ~300,000 unique tags.
Because there are multiple tags per id, there are ~78,000,000 rows, which makes querying quite slow. An example of a query would be `SELECT id FROM tags_table WHERE tag = "flower"`

Would my query execute faster if I made a table of unique tags and modified tags_table to contain the indices of those tag strings instead of the strings themselves? And if so, how would I do that? My goal here is minimize query duration.

Here's the create statement for the table:

`` CREATE TABLE `tags_table` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `tag` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `no_dup_tags` (`id`,`tag`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1; ``

Comment: You forgot the important facts - indexes. Do you have any?

Comment: can you post structure of your table

Comment: @juergend I have one to make id-tag pairs unique but that's all

Comment: @jaidutt How do I do that?

Comment: Just have any index on `tags`, preferable `(tag, id)`. Using a second table will be a bit faster because it will be a lot smaller because the index and the table will contain integer instead of utf8 varchar(200), but it will be a minor speedup compared to using the index, so this can be step 2. The fulltext index from jai would work too. As long as you have any index on `tags` you will be happy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a classic many-to-many mapping table.  On one side is `tag`.  On the other side is `id`, which I assume is an id into some other table?

What you need to have be "unique" is the pair.  This can be limited by either specifying `(id, tag)` to be unique or `(tag, id)` to be unique.  There is no need to specify both to be unique.

"Uniqueness" can be declared either by `UNIQUE(...)` or by `PRIMARY KEY(...)`.

Presumably you want to look up all the `ids` for a given `tag`, *and* you also want to find all the `tags` for a given `id`?  Then you need two indexes, one starting with `tag`, one starting with `id`.

[*Here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) are 7 tips on building the optimal mapping table.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can just make another table with unique tags and apply unique index on that column of tags and replace all tags ans add one more column in your current table to change tags text to id and then simple index that id column.

If you not want any changes just use fulltext index on tag column

```
ALTER TABLE table_name  
ADD FULLTEXT(column_name1)
```

**Note:** MyISAM has FULLTEXT search indexes, InnoDB did not until MySQL 5.6 (Feb 2013).

Comment: Would doing this actually speed up my query significantly?

Comment: What is the purpose of removing the `UNIQUE` ?

Comment: You can check it by put explain in front of your query.  In your current query index length is double.